# build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed error

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, glassfish

Trying to setup glassfish server for netbeans. I started the server and ran the project(default web project) and it gives this error:

In-place deployment at `C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\WebApplication2\build\web`

GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false

```
C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\WebApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045:
```

The module has not been deployed.

See the server log for details.

BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

edit: server log: https://justpaste.it/u702

Comment: Maybe you should provide the server log.

Comment: It was very long. I added it as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Become owner of the Tomcat directory.. On Linux or BSD do this:

chown -R username /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/

To show how's use the command ls-l
He was root now will show your username.

*check in which path to the directory's Tomcat on your distro.